# Yesterday Sales Amount

Tags: dax

We can assume that Yesterday will be the *last non blank date in the Sales table*

How do I add the above logic into the following measure?

```
Yesterday Sales = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[SalesAmount])
    , LASTDATE('Calendar'[Date])
)
```

Currently this measure returns the following:

[image]

This makes sense as the last date in the calendar table is not in the Sales table - so I think I need to change `LASTDATE('Calendar'[Date])` so it only returns the last date that is in the Sales table - how do I do this?

---

note

There is a relationship between the Calendar and Sales table based on a Datekey but there is no Date column in the Sales table.

Comment: What does the `Sales[Datekey]` column look like if it's not a date column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate it based on your date table and the today() function.

```
Yesterday Sales = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[SalesAmount])
    , 'Calendar'[Date] = today()-1
)
```

If you want to be based on your 'date' in the salestable, you could use a max of that field and compare with this field.